# Xamarin Support

Tags: mobilepush, push-notification

I found the SalesForce Component on the Xamarin components store here:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/SalesforceSDK

However there is no mention of MobilePush support. I'm actually only interested in how I might register for notifications with SalesForce after I have the token from Apple APNS and Google GCM. i.e. use a Rest or SOAP API to perform the registration rather than use an interactive SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SalesforceSDK and the Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK are not the same.  The SalesforceSDK is not likely what you are looking for.  Xamarin is known to work, but is unsupported by the SFMC MobilePush SDK.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Do you know of any way to still use MobilePush but without the SDK? Is there an API maybe available?

Comment: The "Fuel" APIs can be used.  Look for documentation at Code@.

Comment: Sorry Bill to keep firing questions at you. I had a look at the FuelSDK-CSharp project (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp) but it doesn't seem to have support for what I want to do. I'm probably confusing Salesforce Push Notifications and Marketing Cloud MobilePush as you have suggested. I'm very new to Salesforce. I'm going to try and create bindings for the SalesforceSDK based on this document https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_client_app_android.htm. It seems it should be supported by the Salesforce SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK team provides native SDKs for Android and iOS as well as wrappers for Cordova and React.

Please open a Voice of Customer request for a Salesforce Supported Xamarin binding.

Comment: Interesting they'd support the lesser -known platforms, but not Xamarin.  It appears that they are closely aligned with Google ecosystem (using Firebase Cloud Messaging), and not Microsoft's (Azure), and that's probably the reason.  Can developers using the MobilePush SDK integrate with Azure instead of Firebase?

Comment: I note that MobilePush SDK has dependencies on GooglePlay Services (which does have Xam libraries), and also AltBeacon.  Does AltBeacon provide a Xamarin library?

Comment: Please confirm the accuracy of these two statements:

1) It appears that the MarketingCloud SDK has a C# version, and MobilePush SDK is the only one you offer that lacks a C# version.  
2) Also, it appears that MobilePush relies on the MarketingCloud SDK.

Comment: Thanks, @BillMote.  How do I create a Voice of Customer request?

Comment: The MobilePush SDK relies on Google Play Services for Push Notifications.  It also relies on Google Play Services for geolocation services.  The MobilePush SDK relies on AltBeacon for Beacon Messaging.  The MobilePush SDK does _NOT_ rely on any other SDKs.  I do not know how to create a Voice of Customer request, but your account executive should know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Our alignment was solely based on customer requests.  Cordova was implemented as it had the most requests.  React was next.  We have not had enough requests for Xamarin to warrant the additional development AND support that is required for additional platforms.  So, the more VOC requests we have for Xamarin the more likely it will be that we can staff for, build and support another platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can find solutions here: https://github.com/taku-ka/SalesforceMarketingCloudSDKXamarin I will keep on working on the solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).