# Xamarin support for MobilePush SDK

Tags: mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

I want to re-ask [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149382/xamarin-support) that is 3 years old.  In the year 2020, does SalesForce provide Xamarin library for MobilePush SDK, or still only platform-specific libraries for iOS and Android?

We can, of course, create our own Xamarin bindings to wrap the iOS and Android libraries, but this really feels like it should be SalesForce's responsibility.