# MarketingCloud SDK - Xamarin Android

Tags: mobilepush, mobilepush-android

I am aware that Xamarin SDKs are not currently on the roadmap for the MarketingCloud SDK as per this question and others: [Xamarin support for MobilePush SDK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308075/xamarin-support-for-mobilepush-sdk)

Has anybody out there got any experience with rolling their own binding for MarketingCloud for Android on Xamarin?

The most recent I've been able to find online is for v 6.1.0 which is almost 2 years old: https://github.com/nventive/Binding.Salesforce.MarketingCloud

Has anybody got anything more up to date they are able to share or some tips or gotchas for binding v7.x?

Comment: I have anecdotal evidence that at least 2 customers have created a binding for the Android SDK's v7.x.  I encouraged them to share their work publicly but they have not yet done so.

Answer (score 2):

You can find solutions here:
https://github.com/taku-ka/SalesforceMarketingCloudSDKXamarin
I will keep on working on the solution

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.